# Why does an order say processing on Magento when a customer pays by bank transfer?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, ce-1.9.0.1, sales

When a customer pays by bank transfer on a Magento checkout, why does the order say it is 'processing' even though the payment has not been made yet.

I have set up in the Magento configuration to say 'pending payment' when an order is placed by bank transfer but for some reason it keeps says 'processing' in the actually order.

Is there any way this can be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing in magento backend System -> COnfiguration -> Payment Methods -> for the specific payment method set new order status to what you want ..

Comment: In the payment methods, I did set it up that any new orders that are placed by bank transfer, the status should be 'Pending' and not 'Processing'.

Is there a reason as to why in the orders, it would still show 'Processing'?